# ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class SchemeRegistry on Android 9

Tags: android, classnotfoundexception, okhttp, android-9.0-pie

I am using the following OkHttp API to set SSL Factory:

```
OkHttpClient.Builder.sslSocketFactory(sslContext.getSocketFactory(), x509TrustManager);
```

To get `sslContext` I need to create `SchemeRegistry`:

```
SchemeRegistry schemeRegistry = new SchemeRegistry();
schemeRegistry.register(new Scheme("https", new SslSocketFactory(sslContext), 443));
```

This produces the following crash, though:

```
ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "org.apache.http.conn.scheme.SchemeRegistry"
```

What can I do to avoid the crash?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The obsolete `SchemeRegistry` class is no longer available on Android P.

If you still want/need to use legacy HTTP API, in addition to

```
useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
```

in `android` section of `build.gradle`, you also need to add

```
    <uses-library
        android:name="org.apache.http.legacy"
        android:required="false" />
```

to `<application>` tag in your Manifest.